# PHPMailer library

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am first time to use the PHPMailer.

(A)

```
require_once "./PHPMailerAutoload.php";
...
```

(B)

```
require_once "./class.phpmailer.php";
...
```

What is the differences between them? I see some page was used A, some page was used B. Are they perform the same thing?

Comment: Pretty much all the ones you will find using the latter will be old examples that should probably be ignored. It's been recommended to use the autoloader since PHPMailer 5.2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code of `PHPMailerAutoload.php`, you'll see it sets up the autoloader via `spl_autoload_register()`;

The second option lets you include the class manually

For an extended usage of a package it is recommended to use the autoloader, as you might need to instantiate other classes in that package and it would avoid the need to manually `require_once` every file, one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing different between two ways using phpmailer. But from PHPMailer version 5.2.7, it's recommended that you use PHPMailerAutoload to include PHPMailer.